# Improve performance when running the same function several times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently coding an app based on Python which runs the same function several times but never with the same arguments.

The goal of the app is to send PowerShell commands to a server via pywinrm module. Here a simplified code snippet which updates permissions on a Windows folder:

```
server = input('Please provide a server: ')
path = input('Provide the path of the folder: ')
permissions = ['Read', 'ReadAndExecute', 'List', 'Write', 'Modify']

run_ps_cmd(server, path, permissions[0])
run_ps_cmd(server, path, permissions[1])
run_ps_cmd(server, path, permissions[2])
run_ps_cmd(server, path, permissions[3])
run_ps_cmd(server, path, permissions[4])
```

For now, it takes 20 seconds to run and I would like to improve the performance but I don't know how. Which direction should I take? Parallelism, threading, multiprocessing, etc...?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Need to see a code example to know which options would help your situation the best. In general, threading is good for I/O bound tasks, multiprocessing is good for CPU bound tasks.

Comment: Hi @CasualDemon, thanks for your input. I have updated my original post with a code snippet to give you better visibility.

Comment: Just a guess because you failed to describe what is the `run_ps_cmd` function that needs optimization. You could first wonder whether if is possible or not to gather relevant data as a whole and then process it locally. If it is not possible, as network is involved, it is likely to be an IO bound task and multithreading could be tried, by running each `run_ps_cmd` in its own thread and then joining all threads. Show relevant code if you want a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get them to just run in parallel, I would simply add them all to a multiprocessing pool.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

server = input('Please provide a server: ')
path = input('Provide the path of the folder: ')
permissions = ['Read', 'ReadAndExecute', 'List', 'Write', 'Modify']

run_ps = partial(run_ps_cmd, (server, path)) 
# required due to how Pool.map only takes an interable 
# to pass each item in it to the function.

p = Pool(processes=5)
results = p.map(run_ps, permissions)
p.terminate()
p.join()
```

In Python 3 it supports being run as a context manager:

```
with Pool(processes=5) as p:
    results = p.map(run_ps, permissions)
```

I would caution against running in parallel without actually knowing the code of `run_ps_cmd` or if a threading pool would suffice if it is I/O bound (in which case switch out `Pool` for `ThreadPool` from `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool`.)

Someone's random article with more information http://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line/

Hope this helps!